# How to signon and rsubmit with user and password option, and suppress autoexec.sas in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a way to Not run autoexec.sas, during remote signon and rsubmit? 
I have tried `sascmd="sas -noautoexec"` but it conflicts with the `user=` and `password=` options.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the behaviour you are experiencing. Provide details of both your normal remote signon and the full code you have tried so far for avoiding the autoexec.

Comment: %let server = unix.penn.edu 4016;
options comamid=TCP 
signon server nocscript sascmd='sas -noautoexec' user=aaa  password=bbb;
Rsubmit;

Answer (score 0):

You can do as suggested by he wei
%let server = unix.penn.edu 4016; options comamid=TCP signon server nocscript sascmd='sas -noautoexec' user=aaa password=bbb; Rsubmit;

Or use another include in the program you want to recreate the macro variable user and password.